# No me carga el javascript en django 1.11

Tags: javascript, django

Estoy realizando un sitio web en `django`, pero al momento de ejecutar la aplicación carga el HTML y CSS pero no el JavaScript, ¿por qué será? Los errores mostrados, son los siguientes:

> ```
>   [28/Sep/2017 14:02:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 26231
>     [28/Sep/2017 14:02:23] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>     [28/Sep/2017 14:02:23] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>     [28/Sep/2017 14:02:23] "GET /static/css/flexslider.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>     [28/Sep/2017 14:02:23] "GET /static/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>     [28/Sep/2017 14:02:23] "GET /static/css/zoomslider.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>     [28/Sep/2017 14:02:23] "GET /static/css/font-awesome.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>     [28/Sep/2017 14:02:23] "GET /static/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>     [28/Sep/2017 14:02:23] "GET /static/js/jquery.zoomslider.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>     [28/Sep/2017 14:02:23] "GET /static/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>     [28/Sep/2017 14:02:23] "GET /static/js/simplePlayer.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
>     [28/Sep/2017 14:02:23] "GET /static/js/jquery.flexslider.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
> ```

Comment: Añade tu archivo de settings.py y de urls.py

Comment: Hernán, mira aquí [qué funciones tiene este sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Recuerda [edit] tu pregunta para que los demás usuarios puedan ayudarte. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El código de estado 304 no es de error, significa que el archivo no fue modificado y se sirve el mismo.

Tal vez debas ejecutar `collectstatic` si editaste el archivo y no se refleja en la app, y recargarla presionando la tecla "Ctrl".